# Migrate x86 printer drivers to arm [Brother]

Tags: x86, arm

I have a Brother DCP 197C printer and I would like to print from my phone using a raspberry pi. To archieve it I need to install drivers, but brother only provide x86 and x64 drivers, any way to do it? Thanks!
The driver download link:
https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=es&lang=es&prod=dcp197c_eu&os=128&flang=English

Comment: I would argue that this is very much on-topic, but that it doesn't show any effort on part of the inquirer to achieve it and therefore isn't specific enough. What you are looking for, in effect, could be done with **code lifting** (or as described in the single answer existing at this point). Code lifting has a huge potential for reverse engineers and could - in theory - be used to re-target binaries.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really related to reverse engineering and might be a better fit for another StackExchange site.

That said, I would look into using the x86/x86_64 [QEMU with USB passthrough](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/usb.html) in full-system mode. Basically it will be running a small x86 virtual machine with that driver loaded and passing the USB device directly through to the VM. Then you can set something up to let the Raspberry Pi host send print jobs into the VM (e.g. through a listening lpr/CUPS server).